# How can i select value of static select_tag on my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @guest_server, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :current_uid %>
  <%= label_tag 'Sippeer Type' %>
  <%= select_tag "sippeer_type", options_for_select([ "Conference", "Trunk" ]) %>
  <%= f.input :sippeer_template_id %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                guest_servers_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this is my controller i want to get the value of sippeer_type

```
def create
  @guest_server = GuestServer.new(guest_server_params)
  if guest_server_params[:sippeer_type] == 'Conference'
    @guest_server.set_confbridge_sippeer
  else
    @guest_server.set_sippeer
  end
end
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask. There is no question in this one. Be more specific.

Comment: Also please include your code which sets `guest_server_params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params[:sippeer_type]` to get the value. It's not embedded in a subarray because it's not using the form helper.